# yii2 - redirect from view to another view

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to redirect from a View to another View and I cannot find a solution online.

I have tried using:

```
Yii::$app->request->redirect(Yii::$app->createAbsoluteUrl("site/view"));
```

But I receive the following error:

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
>
> Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::createAbsoluteUrl()

Comment: But if I use Yii::$app->response->redirect('site/hat'); my url is changing to /web/site/hat which does not exist. The right url is index.php?r=site/hat

Comment: @soju thanks so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use [`response`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$response-detail) instead of `request` :

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/view']);
```

You can also use [`Url`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail) helper to get an absolute url :

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['site/view'], true));
```

And if you want to use [`createAbsoluteUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#createAbsoluteUrl()-detail) :

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/view']));
```

Comment: Thank you. I receive the same error: Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::createAbsoluteUrl()

Comment: I knew how to do it from the controller but not from the view

Answer (score 1):

If you use $app then use it always  use

```
Yii::$app->request->redirect(Yii::$app->createAbsoluteUrl("site/hat"));
```

instead of

```
Yii::$app->request->redirect(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("site/hat"));
```

or you can use this for get the url

```
Yii::$app->request->redirect(['site/hat']));
```

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately it doesn't seems to be that the problem. I receive a new error. let me update the question

Comment: Thank you but I get this error: Calling unknown method: yii\web\Request::redirect()

Comment: I have now found the answer finally! I will update the question.